# Angular, ERROR TypeError: items.filter is not a function

Tags: angular, angular5

I have such an error in the browser console:

```ts
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: items.filter is not a function
TypeError: items.filter is not a function
at FilterByFieldPipe.push../src/app/pipes/filter-by-field.ts.FilterByFieldPipe.transform (filter-by-field.ts:11)
at TaskListComponent.push../src/app/components/tasks/list.ts.TaskListComponent.refreshPipes (list.ts:139)
at TaskListComponent.push../src/app/components/tasks/list.ts.TaskListComponent.refreshTasks (list.ts:129)
at list.ts:29
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3654)
........
```

From this file.

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByField',
  pure: false
})

export class FilterByFieldPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items, key, value) {
    if (items) {
      return items.filter((item) => item[key] === value);
    }
  }
}
```

Elements are created, I can see them, the problem is that they are not output all together.

This is the model file:

app.module.ts

```ts
import { BrowserModule }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }                   from '@angular/core';
import {
ReactiveFormsModule,
FormsModule,
FormBuilder,
FormGroup,
Validators
}                                     from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }                 from '@angular/http';
import { environment }                from '../environments/environment';
import { APP_CONFIG, appConfig }      from './app.config';
import { AppRoutingModule }           from './app.routes';
import { AuthService }                from './services/auth';
import { TaskService }                from './services/task';
import { AppComponent }               from './components/app';
import { LoginComponent }             from './components/login';
import { NavbarComponent }            from './components/navbar';
import { InlineEditComponent }        from './components/inline-edit';
import { RegistrationComponent }      from './components/registration';
import { ConfirmEmailComponent }      from './components/confirm-email';
import { AdminComponent }             from './components/admin';
import { TasksComponent }             from './components/tasks';
import { TaskListComponent }          from './components/tasks/list';
import { TaskFormComponent }          from './components/tasks/form';
import { TasksDetailComponent }       from './components/tasks/detail';
import { TasksDetailInlineComponent } from './components/tasks/detail-inline';
import { TaskEditComponent }          from './components/tasks/edit';
import { SimpleNotificationsModule }  from 'angular2-notifications';
import { MyDatePickerModule }         from 'mydatepicker';
// import { NgbModule }                  from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-        bootstrap';
import './rxjs-extensions';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
LoginComponent,
RegistrationComponent,
ConfirmEmailComponent,
NavbarComponent,
AdminComponent,
TasksComponent,
TaskListComponent,
TaskFormComponent,
TasksDetailComponent,
TasksDetailInlineComponent,
InlineEditComponent,
TaskEditComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
AppRoutingModule,
SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MyDatePickerModule/*,
NgbModule.forRoot()*/
],
providers: [
AuthService,
TaskService,
FormBuilder,
Validators,
{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useFactory: appConfig }
],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you share your data model?

Comment: could you console log the value of items. It just seems this is not an array, so the filter function does not exists on it.

Comment: Model != module. We can't currently see how you're calling the pipe, with what, so it's unclear why you expected it to be an array. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: to be exact it would be nice if you could provide us an example of "items" which are used in your pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement add a check if items are equal to the array. Without it, you will get error messages when you use your pipe on the wrong type of data.

You can do it by comparing `items.constructor === Array` or just add `items: array<any>`.

I would suggest you upgrade version of your project. Many answers which you look for or will be looking for might not work for you just because of so old version of the project.